# How can a C program poll for user input while simultaneously performing other actions in a Linux environment?

Tags: c, linux

**Background:**

I'm a relatively inexperienced developer trying to write software to interface with a PCI motion controller. I'm using C (compiled with gcc) on Ubuntu Linux 18.04.

The program I'm writing needs to regularly check for unsolicited status messages sent by the motion controller (approx. once per second) and display any messages it finds on a terminal screen (for which I'm using the `ncurses` library).

**What I have:**

Right now, to do this, I'm calling a function that checks for unsolicited messages in a while loop. The code is roughly akin to:

```
while (1)
{
    // check for messages from PCI and store them in a traffic buffer
    checkForMessages(PCIconnection, trafficBuffer);

    // output the traffic buffer to the screen
    printf("%s", trafficBuffer);    
}
```

**What I need:**

I need the user to be prompted for input in a way that allows them to end the loop. For example, the user could input `end` causing the loop to stop and the program to continue.

**The problem:**

I'm not aware of a way to achieve this without putting `fgets` inside the while loop, causing the program to stop and wait for the user to input something on every loop iteration.

I've looked for a solution, but I haven't been able to find discussion on how to achieve the functionality I need. Opening a new thread or process seems like a step in the right direction?

I'm open to completely restructuring my code if what I'm currently doing is poor practice.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your task requires an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) based on `select` or `epoll`. One event it would wait for is user input - when `STDIN_FILENO` becomes ready for read. Another is the 1-second periodic timer when you need to poll the controller.

There are quite a few libraries that implement an event loop for you so that you can focus on what events you need to handle and how. [`libevent`](https://libevent.org/) is one of the oldest, feature rich and popular.

Comment: Thank you for answering! This is definitely a valid answer to the question I asked, so I'm accepting it. After a lot more reading, I also discovered that there's an answer built into ```ncurses``` itself. Calling the function ```timeout``` and passing it ```0``` makes ```getch``` (an ```ncurses``` input function) non-blocking, which also solved my problem.

Comment: The problem with this is that you're likely to have a busy-waiting loop that takes 100% of your cpu time, unless you use some variant of sleep, which makes responding to input non-immediate in most cases. `select`/`poll`, or a library that's based on those, would almost certainly have less undesirable side effects.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer is multi-threading, where you have thread deployed to wait for user input, while loop continues on. So have this:

```
char flag = 1;

while (flag) {
     // run the loop

     // if thing happens deploy the thread which will ask user for input

}
```

I have not done threading in a while, I think this page would be better than me trying to explain it to you:
https://randu.org/tutorials/threads/

Comment: But see [5 Big Fat Reasons Why Mutexes Suck Big Time](https://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload149.pdf) for a few considerations on multi-threading.

Comment: Yes, I'd didn't have much of a feel one way or the other about where and what kind of pitfalls were involved in multithreading until that article was posted on the *accu-general* mailing list `accu-general@accu.org`. It makes some very good points on the inherent inability to validate multithreaded code.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I would include link in my answer but it does not appear to work.

Comment: Damn, I hate it when sites break their old links. They completely redid their site, all issues of Overload are now found at [Past Issues of Overload Journal](https://accu.org/journals/nonmembers/overload_issue_members/) and [Overload Issue - 149](https://accu.org/journals/overload/27/149/overload149.pdf) holding that link is there.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the "Unix" way would be not to ask for user input, but to react to a user signal. For example, when the user presses Ctrl-C, the currently running process receives SIGINT.

An example how to properly use SIGINT to interrupt a loop can be found [here](http://lazarenko.me/signal-handler/). Copying it into the answer in case the link gets stale:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static volatile sig_atomic_t got_signal = 0;

static void my_sig_handler(int signo)
{
    got_signal = 1;
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa;

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    sa.sa_handler = &my_sig_handler;
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (;;) {
        if (got_signal) {
            got_signal = 0;
            printf("Received interrupt signal!\n");
        }
        printf("Doing useful stuff...\n");
        sleep(1); /* Sleep is not only useful, it is essential! */
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

(in your case it would be a good idea to put `break;` into the `if` block or to use `while(!got_signal)`)